How can I get Grafana to interpret a variable operation then a range vector
Grafana fails to interpret query: count_over_time((metric <$variable) [$__range]) correctly. How can I get Grafana to perform the variable operation on the metric's value first then apply the function for the range?  I keep getting the message that a scalar is not allowed for a range vector.
I've tried to apply an expression threshold for range to the query scalar operation only (metric <$inactivity) with the limits being the global variables ${__from} and ${__to} with no success.
I'm expecting the ability to apply the Grafana UI range values from the date picker to the query after a variable operation has been performed on the metric's value.
There is no way to pass the Grafana UI range directly into my Oracle query so I'm stuck trying find a solution in the Grafana query builder.
Grafana version: 10.4.5
Prometheus version: 2.45.6

Grafana already does everything needed in this situation. Problem is within your query itself: range selector can be directly applied only to vector selector. Since you have something more complex, you need to use subquery syntax. For query mentioned in question this means you need to simply ad: after $__range

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thanks @markalex , I took your suggestion and identified the correct syntax for the problem as: (count_over_time(metric [$__range:] )< $variable) .
